# The number of intersections between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the count of intersections between column pairs.
The datafile(tsb) and expected result are like this.
The number of rows per columns are not same so I want to ignore the empty space.

Data(tsb)

```
C1 C2 C3 C4
A  B  A  A
C  F  B  B
F  C  C   
G     H
H
```

Result

```
C1_C2 C1_C3 C1_C4 C2_C3 C2_C4 C3_C4
  2     3     1     2     1     2
```

I am doing this by changing each column into list and doing something like `C1_C2 = len(set(C1) & set(C2))` but the size of column is more than 100, I want to find better way.

Comment: A column size of 100 shouldn't be a problem, or do you mean that there are in excess of 100 columns?

Comment: I meant that I am comparing columns one by one by hand, so I want to know some way to deal whole combinations of columns in bulk, though the size of column is huge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your file into a pandas dataframe, you will have the equivalent of

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'C2':['B', 'F', 'C', '', ''], 'C3':['A', 'B', 'C', 'H', ''], 'C4':['A', 'B', '', '', '']})
```

Then you can define a function:

```
def findInter(pair):
    return (pair[0]+ '_' + pair[1], len(set(list(df[pair[0]])) & set(list(df[pair[1]]))))
```

and you get the result:

```
map(findInter, itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2))
```

Comment: It works fine, although little difficult for me for total understanding. Thank you very much.